# Mapsforge analog for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, maps, vector-graphics

I need some framework for my iPhone app, which is using maps. Now these maps are raster images and I'd like to optimize my app by doing vector maps instead. I know that my colleagues from Android development had used Mapsforge framework for this purposes. Is there any analog of this library for iPhone? I need framework that could quickly render vector maps using hardware acceleration, caching maps, offline rendering and (optinal) be cross-platform. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following post: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/route-me-map/wbBa4h0R_iw

> There is … **libosmscout** that do vector maps drawing (unix, windows,
>   QT, iOS, Android, …), routing, searching:
>
> https://sourceforge.net/projects/libosmscout/
>
> I did the iOS/OSX drawing code, it's not finished but works quite
>   well.

Answer (score 3):

ok, I've moved over my laziness and decided to move to github my forgotten almost year-ago work. This is Mapsforge for iOS, dirty code, but it should work without any additional setup. It can read .map files and asynchronously render tiles with vector objects to mapView. You can find it here: https://github.com/medvedNick/Mapsforge_iOS

Comment: It doesn't appear to run. It crashes immediately after it starts. This is on iOS 6.

Comment: @Calin I've just cloned the repo from github and run it on my iPad 3 with iOS 6.1 - it is working. Can you provide more information about crash: console log and stacktrace? or contact me directly at medvednick@yandex.ru

Comment: @Calin maybe you are running it for iPhone 5? then you should to set up "architectures" option in "Summary" tab for all subprojects - there is no armv7s for now, and I have neither iPhone 5 nor time to fix it now. If you have this fixed - feel free to make pull request

Comment: I didn't think to look at that, I tried it in the simulator if I remember right. I'll try it again and do a pull request if necessary. Thanks